# How do I make sure that RegEx returns false when a slash is at the end?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a search pattern done so I get the video URL on certain portals. 
For one particular site I've been using this:

```
/www.website.net\/category\/[a-z-]*\/[a-z-]*\/[0-9a-z]*^[^\/]/
```

on
    www.website.net/category/topic/more/abcde/

in order to say 'the string matches' only if there isn't a slash after the abcde part. I now managed to do this, but even if the slash at the end is gone it doesn't return any matches. What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

I now settled for

```
/www.website.net\/category\/[a-z-]*\/[a-z-]*\/[0-9a-z]*[^\/]+$/
```

in order to only prevent the match if there is a slash, since the video URL at the back also has a string in the format /abcde-here-comes-video-name. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to match both **"www.website.net/category/topic/more/abcde/"** and **"www.website.net/category/topic/more/abcde"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about checking for the end of the string using `$`:

```
/www.website.net\/category\/[a-z-]*\/[a-z-]*\/[0-9a-z]*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Near the end of your regex, you have "^[^/]". The first caret (^) shouldn't be there.

Comment: That `^` is definitely incorrect (+1), but removing it still doesn't solve his problem (-1).